# How to increase the speed sql query and get fastly record

Tags: postgresql

I have a large set of records in my database. I tried to run SQL query using where condition. I got the data and I show count of records also. It taking around 21 secs. I need to reduce the time.

**Sql Query**

```
select * from sample_rank where company_id = 1
```

**Records Count**

```
166270266
```

I added Index in db. but It's not fastly getting data. How to fix it and How to change the query

Comment: *and I show count of records also* Total or matched? *I got the data* all 166kk rows? *I added Index in db.* WHAT index?

Comment: Which one is your DBMS :`Postgres`, `SQL Server` or `MySQL` ..? Btw, you added the index on `sample_rank.company_id` column, did you ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you really need to do `SELECT *`?  If you don't need all columns, then which ones do you need?

Comment: @Akina  Matched Count. I added Indexes in db

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan Postgresql DB .Yes I added Index sample_rank

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I don't need all columns. I nedd two columns only

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, going by your comments, that you only need to select *two* of the columns in your table:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM sample_rank WHERE company_id = 1;
```

then the following *covering* index is probably the best you can do here:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON sample_rank (company_id, col1, col2);
```

The above index completely covers the entire query, meaning that, **if** used, your SQL engine can use the index alone to satisfy the entire query plan.  I put "if" in bold, because depending on the cardinality of the data, the above index might not help the query run faster.  For example, if you only have two `company_id` values, 1 and 2, with 50% of the record having each value, then your SQL engine might just decide that a full table scan would be faster than even resorting to use the index.  As suggested in the comments, running `EXPLAIN` on your actual query would reveal more information.